# taxonomy terms, inverted

Tags: taxonomy, terms

I have a taxonomy that will be the brand, and the children’s items the template.
[image]

I have a code in `single.php` to show the details.

```
        <div class="box2">
        <div class="faixa">
            <div class="marca">MARCA  <div class="marca">
            <?php 


            $term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('fields' => 'names', 'parent' => 0));

            if ( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {
            //  echo $term_names[0];
             var_dump($term_names);

}

            ?>

            </div></div>
            <div class="modelo">MODELO  <div class="marca">

            <?php 

            $term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('fields' => 'names' ));

            if ( ! empty( $term_names ) ) {
            // echo $term_names[0];
              var_dump($term_names);

}

            ?>
            </div></div>  
        </div>
```

The result is this:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/VsD1xhL]

But there are some that appear inverted ?! because ?
[image]

I have described all the parts I have done below:

[image]

So far only the FIAT brand, and UNO model that inverts .. Maybe it’s being organized by alphabetical order or something?

Answer (score 0):

yes it's because you sort them by name and in order ASCending.
because `'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'` is the default setting.

try:
`$term_names = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('fields' => 'names', 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'DESC', ));`

and it should be the other way around.

here you have documentation of which parameters are possible with orderby and order: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

**edit:**
maybe you want it like this (not quite sure about the correct syntax in detail):

```
<div class="box2">
            <div class="faixa">
                <div class="marca">MARCA  <div class="marca">
                <?php 


                $parents = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('parent' => 0));

                if ( ! empty( $parents ) ) {
                //  echo $parents[0];
                 var_dump($parents);

    }

                ?>

                </div></div>
                <div class="modelo">MODELO  <div class="marca">

                <?php 

                $childs = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('fields' => 'names', 'parent' => $parents[0]->ID ));

                if ( ! empty( $childs ) ) {
                // echo $childs[0];
                  var_dump($childs);

    }

                ?>
                </div></div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: Then everything will go wrong. when my parent => 0 what is the brand, with another name?
https://imgur.com/a/NhAwW0a

Comment: could you explain more precisely what you want to achieve? in the first var_dump() you want have the parent and in the second var_dump() you want to see the parent with it's childs listed before?

Comment: Yes, the parent item is the brand of the vehicle and the child item is the model of the vehicle.

Comment: you could save your brand into a variable. in the second loop just output the childs by configuring `wp_get_post_terms` filter with the `parent` option. you will need the ID of your parent for that, like: `$childs = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'marcamodelo', array('fields' => 'names', 'parent' => $parentID));`

Comment: i try all and nothing for model uno is inverse.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sMKF01S

Answer (score 0):

I solved:
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'marcamodelo' );
            if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
            // get the first term
            //  var_dump ($terms);
            echo $terms[0]->name;
            }

and

$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'marcamodelo' );
            if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
            // get the first term
            //  var_dump ($terms);
            echo $terms[1]->name;
            }